# What relation must hold between sets A and B in order for the given condition to be true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$(A \cap B)' = B'$$

Where `'` represents complement.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $X'=Y'$ if and only if $X=Y$. When is $A\cap B=B$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The fact that $(A\cap B)'=A'\cup B'$ may make seeing things easier.

Answer (score 1):

Taking complements of both side $A\cap B=B\Rightarrow B\subset A$.